# Javascript RegEx to MASK 24 hour and minute (hh:mm)

Tags: javascript, regex

I've spend almost an hour reading similar posts but still no success on formating a single input field to mask input values in format (00:00).

So far here's the code but don't know why it doesn't work:

```
    $('.houronly').keyup(function(){
        this.value=this.value.toString().replace(/^(([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]|[0-9])|([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]|[0-9])(:|h)[0-5]?[0-9]?)$/, "$1");
    });
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide sample input and output

Comment: How about keeping it simple and just cancelling the key event if a invalid value is entered? That way, you don't have to try to parse every single possible input.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R by **mask** I meant whatever user inputs... If it inputs a letter it must be deleted and accept only numbers and `:`, in the appropriate range, of course.

Comment: And accept 23h too, for example, right?

Comment: Ranges are `00:00` to `23:59`. I thought that it should be trivial, instead of loading a whole library (jQuery plugins) to do that, such as jQuery datetime, etc...

Comment: Its not clear yet. Are you expecting and input like `23:45` or `somethign 23:54` or `12:45h` or `sdf234:234`

Comment: All of that and also `asdfkja` and `kkdiwkwkwkwkekrjeçklqwje` and the other zillion possible inputs trough a keyboard..........

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take this as a toy answer if you like, but I made a method to mask the 24h time input **as the user types it** because in your question you have

```
$('.houronly').keyup(function(){ .. }
```

so I presume you want masking while the user is typing.

As the user types in 24h clock times, impossible key sequences should be truncated or rejected on the fly. I made a series of replacement rules that build on previous rules to accomplish this. When the input loses focus, a final check for 24h time validity is performed.

Now, in your original regex, you have `(:|h)` so I assume you want to allow times formatted like "23h".

**Code:**

```
function replaceBadInputs(val) {
  // Replace impossible inputs as they appear
  val = val.replace(/[^\dh:]/, "");
  val = val.replace(/^[^0-2]/, "");
  val = val.replace(/^([2-9])[4-9]/, "$1");
  val = val.replace(/^\d[:h]/, "");
  val = val.replace(/^([01][0-9])[^:h]/, "$1");
  val = val.replace(/^(2[0-3])[^:h]/, "$1");      
  val = val.replace(/^(\d{2}[:h])[^0-5]/, "$1");
  val = val.replace(/^(\d{2}h)./, "$1");      
  val = val.replace(/^(\d{2}:[0-5])[^0-9]/, "$1");
  val = val.replace(/^(\d{2}:\d[0-9])./, "$1");
  return val;
}

// Apply input rules as the user types or pastes input
$('.houronly').keyup(function(){
  var val = this.value;
  var lastLength;
  do {
    // Loop over the input to apply rules repeately to pasted inputs
    lastLength = val.length;
    val = replaceBadInputs(val);
  } while(val.length > 0 && lastLength !== val.length);
  this.value = val;
});

// Check the final result when the input has lost focus
$('.houronly').blur(function(){
  var val = this.value;
  val = (/^(([01][0-9]|2[0-3])h)|(([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])$/.test(val) ? val : "");
  this.value = val;
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsbin.com/xutebu/1/watch?js,output)

Answer (score 3):

How about the regex

```
\b(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\b
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/gM7qO7/1)

**Test**

```
var string="hello its 23:54. Some random value";
string = string.match(/\b(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\b/g)[0];
console.log(string);
// Outputs
// => 23:54
```

Comment: You can actually assign it to the input variable so that it is replaced by the digits. See the Test part in the edited answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Why'd you prefix JS variables with `$`?

Comment: @Cerbrus I was in a hurry :P . removed

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
box_open = document.querySelector('.msg-time');
$.mask.definitions['H'] = "[0-2]";
$.mask.definitions['h'] = "[0-9]";
$.mask.definitions['M'] = "[0-5]";
$.mask.definitions['m'] = "[0-9]";
$(".open").mask("Hh:Mm", {
    completed: function() {
       $(this).text().substr(0, 2);
       if (parseInt($(this).val()) > 23){
           box_open.innerHTML ='<div class="alert alert-danger"> Invalid time!</div>';';
         $(".open").val("");
        };      
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class='msg-time'></div>
<div>
  <label>Open</label>
    <input type="text" class="open" name="open"  id="open">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this ([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])
or (2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])

```
var re = /([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])/;

var str = "12:48";

var myArray = str.match(re);
var hours = str.replace(re, "$1");
var minutes = str.replace(re, "$2");

console.log(myArray);
console.log(hours);
console.log(minutes);
```

Comment: So, what if a user enters `"12:48a"`?